# Database comparison

Tags: database, comparison

Which industry-class database has the most **unique** features? (with "unique" meaning that no other RDBMS has them)

I think my choice here is Oracle 11g:

1. Flashback query (you can estract data as it was a moment in the past)
2. ASM - automatic storage management
3. Native code compilation of stored procedures
4. Audit features (tracing everything, from logins to statements)

and many others.

Answer (score 2):

Funny, I rate vendors by their conformance with the ANSI/ISO SQL Standards e.g. for SQL Server my shopping list is deferrable `CHECK` constraints that support subqueries and proper support for `DOMAIN`s and `ASSERTION`s -- and these date from as long ago as SQL-92. For me, vendors should put in proprietary features only after they've implemented the Standard ones :)

Comment: That's because you aren't thinking from the point of view of a DBA/sysadmin, but from the programmer one. You should consider every aspect.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems && http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_object-relational_database_management_systems would be where I'd start.

As to truly "unique" features? I've seen things I thought were unique that turned out to be common once I did more digging :)

Comment: Thanks for the great links, but I was really looking for "uncommon" features that are unique. For example, which db, Oracle apart, has flashback query?

Comment: I'd have to agree with @onedaywhen - I want the standard implemented; the unique features may or may not be useful because when I need to change RDBMSes, I don't want to be doing proprietrary things :)

Comment: "flashback query" isn't something you would use in a program, but it's incredibly handy, indeed (you can see an object as it was at a certain point in the past), and makes the difference comparing Oracle to other databases, IMHO.